# How to set PageRank and Hits parameters by using JUNG?

Tags: java, jung, pagerank

I'm trying to use PageRank and Hits algorithm on a DirectedSparseGraph I have build from a Wikipedia Dump. The graph is huge obviously and its nodes are String, while its Edge are Integer. The problem is that when I run this code:

```
PageRank<String,Integer> pageRank = new PageRank<String,Integer>(w, alpha);
pageRank.initialize();  
pageRank.setTolerance(0.000001);
pageRank.setMaxIterations(200);
pageRank.evaluate();

HITS<String, Integer> hits = new HITS<String, Integer>(w,alpha);
hits.initialize();
hits.setTolerance(0.000001);
hits.setMaxIterations(200);
hits.evaluate();
for(String s: w.getVertices()){
    writer.write(s + "\th:" + hits.getVertexScore(s).hub + "\ta:" + hits.getVertexScore(s).authority + "\tpagerank:" + pageRank.getVertexScore(s));
    writer.newLine();
}
```

the results I'm writing on the file txt are always the same for each Node.
Maybe I am making a mistake with parameters I pass the methods. I don't know.

Answer (score 0):

How big is the graph?  How many iterations are actually being performed?

If the values are simply 1/n (where n is the number of vertices) then what's probably happening here is that it's exiting immediately (which you can check).

The other obvious possibility is that you made a mistake in constructing the graph and made it symmetric, so the scores would all be identical.  You should be able to check this pretty easily, too.

Comment: Why does it exit immediately in the first case?

Comment: The graph contains 34308 nodes. It performs 200 iterations for PageRank and 200 for Hits after the execution.
The results for each node are near to 1/n but not exactly 1/n.

Comment: It could be exiting immediately if the tolerance for change is high enough.

Comment: Your comment contradicts your original post: it states that the values are near-but-not-exactly 1/n, whereas the original post states that the values are the same for all nodes.  Which is it?

Comment: In my first post I said values are the same for all nodes, right! 
I have not said values are all 1/n. Now the values are near to 1/n and are all the same.

Comment: If the values don't sum to 1 (which I infer from the conjunction of "all the same" and "not 1/n") then you've probably done something wrong with the edge weights; another option is that the graph has no edges.  Another thing to look at: does it matter how many iterations you use, or do you always get the same result?

Comment: The number of iterations doesn't change the result. Only alpha value changes it. I have checked the results and in every case they are all 2.837379368947091E-5 except 20 or 30 nodes. Theese nodes have 6.213860817994128E-5 as value.

Comment: If the number of iterations doesn't change the result, then I'd suggest changing the threshold to something smaller, as I suggested earlier.  Your threshold is not much smaller than the values you currently have; the deltas are probably smaller than the deltas.  Try reducing it to 1E-7 or 1E-8 and see what happens.

Comment: I've tried to change treshold but nothing change. The only way to change some value is to change alpha value.

Comment: Is also possible that those are indeed the right answers.  If they correlate well with degree, it could just be that simple.  Do you have some a priori reason to believe that the answers your getting are wrong?

Comment: I think that when I've created my Graph using JUNG, maybe I have done a mistake, even if when I print the Graph it seems all right. I mean that maybe the graph is not well prepared to begin the pagerank. Anyway I thank you for the time you are spending helping me.

Comment: Problem solved! I have right values now : ) 
When I build the graph many Edges weren't been added becouse of a control I made. Thank you for your help Joshua : D

Comment: I'm glad that you figured it out.  I was wondering whether you had some missing edges but it seemed unlikely that you could have added some, but not all, so I hadn't gotten to that suggestion yet.  :)

Comment: Don't worry, Thank you for your help anyway : )